# Call Firebase Cloud function without Triggers

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am trying to deploy a web app to Firebase Hosting which has following features

1) Sending SMS using NEXMO API

2) Display all the Firebase DB Values in a Table

3) Decrypt the Values which are fetched from Firebase DB

The Firebase does not support server side handling of code except Firebase Cloud Functions

I want to call the functions to send SMS, declare app Firebase DB config and fetch values to HTML Pages, and decrypt the values using Firebase Cloud Functions. But I am unable to figure out a way to do that

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly you're trying to accomplish here.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want is to [Serve Dynamic Content with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions).

You can setup your Firebase Hosting to point to a Firebase Function when going to a specific URL path. This allows you to perform server-side processing of the page before serving it to the browser and would allow you to decrypt the fetched values or do any server side tasks before the page is rendered.

The documentation I have linked to above shows you the steps for setting this up, and I would also suggest you have a look at how [HTTP Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) work, as they are what you would use when linking to Firebase Hosting.